# How to find similarities in datasets in one table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have a table with the following data:

```
id  selection
--- ---------
1   x
1   y
1   z
1   k
2   a
2   b
2   c
2   i
3   x
3   a
3   v
3   m
4   x
4   y
4   d
4   z
```

How can I write a query to find which "sets" are either identical or similar? For example, `id` 1 and `id` 4 both have `selection` values "x" and "y". I'm thinking some kind of pivot function, but it would have to be dynamic, since the `selection` values are not a small set of values, but rather a very large set (hundreds, even thousands of possibilities), and I can't list them all out.

"similar": having more than one common `selection` value match
"most similar": having the most common `selection` value matches

e.g. `id` 1 and `id` 4 are the most "similar" in that they have three matching `selection` values.

I want to find the most similar sets. The pseudo-data is limited for space constraints, but imagine that each set can have n number of `selection` values, so, some set might have two matching `selection` values (low similarity), where as others might have 5 or 10 matching `selection` values (5=more similarity; 10=high similarity).

Comment: Does `similar` have any criteria that how many values should be matched ?

Comment: Your question is ill-formed.  What do you mean by "similar"?  1 overlaps with 3 and 4.  2 overlaps with 3.  Hence, all four are connected by chains of overlaps.

Comment: "similar" doesn't help us help you.  Please describe what "similar" is.

Comment: I have added a definition for "similar" to make my question more clear.

Comment: Is `n` a constant or could sets have varying numbers of `selection` values? If it can vary then is 10 matches out of 20 values _more similar_ than 10 matches out of 50 values? Can a `selection` value be repeated within a set, i.e. could there be two occurrences of `'y'` in set `4`? What would that mean for matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know what you want, but here would be a script to start.  Change the value in the where clause if you must match a certain number of entries.  Remove it entirely if one match is enough.

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.ID AS first_id, 
        b.id AS second_id, 
        a.selection,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY a.id, b.id) AS cnt
    FROM your_table a
    INNER JOIN your_table b
    ON a.selection = b.selection
    AND a.ID < b.ID
    ) AS X
WHERE x.cnt >= 2
ORDER BY X.first_id, x.second_id
```

Comment: thank you, i'm glad someone understood what i was getting at. I will try this....

Comment: this is going in the right direction.... but maybe my question wasn't clear.... i want to look at all sets and find the "most similar" sets (those with the most matching values in their sets). any thoughts?

Comment: Actually I think this DOES work. I sorted by "x.cnt" to get the records with the most matching values.

Comment: I'm glad that worked.  To be honest, I wasn't sure that's what you were looking for, but i figured if it wasn't you could have clarified.